# input file in directory which is not in same directory as script being run

Tags: python, argv

I have a bunch of modules in say:

```
modules/module1
```

which is not located in the directory I want to input a file.

at the moment I go to directory which contains file and I run:

```
from module1 import calc
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()
calc(cwd)
```

I would like to reduce this to the simplest as possible, i.e. import the module calc from anywhere and run `calc(cwd)` without having to input the cwd every time. Is there a way to tell calc that you aren't in the module directory but somewhere else? If I just run `calc()` it thinks the file is inside modules/ when it isn't.

The goal is to just cd into a directory and run calc in that directory on a text file which always has the same name (a file containing diagnostic information).

I have added the module1 folder to python path and **init**.py so I can already import all my modules from anywhere.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add code like this to your `module1`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os
    calc(os.getcwd())
```

Since you can import the module from anywhere, if you now do

```
python -m module1
```

then the `__main__` code will run in that directory.